# Updating cedet 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs24

I'm currently on emacs24 on OS X.

```
CEDET Version:  1.0
                        Requested       File            Loaded
  Package               Version         Version         Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:                1.0             nil             ok
  eieio:                1.3             nil             ok
  semantic:             2.0             nil             ok
  srecode:              1.0             nil             Not Loaded
  ede:                  1.0             nil             Not Loaded
  speedbar:             1.0             nil             Not Loaded
```

emacs24 comes with cedet and I am trying to upgrade cedet 1.0 to 1.1 . I compiled cedet with :

```
emacs -Q -nw -l cedet-build.el -f cedet-build -f save-buffers-kill-terminal
```

and added `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/common/cedet.el")` to `.emacs` after which cedet told me all was fine and dandy

```
CEDET Version:  1.1
                        Requested       File            Loaded
  Package               Version         Version         Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:                1.1             ok              ok
  eieio:                1.4             ok              ok
  semantic:             2.1             ok              ok
  srecode:              1.1             ok              ok
  ede:                  1.1             ok              ok
  speedbar:             1.0.4           ok              ok
  cogre:                1.1             ok              Not Loaded
  cedet-contrib:        1.1             ok              Not Loaded
```

however when I try to run it, semantic-mode crashes like a led zeppelin:

> Autoloading failed to define function semantic-mode

I haven't tried running it on emacs23, I don't have emacs23 installed on my system. I don't also have macports or fink, I installed emacs using homebrew. So its vanilla emacs.

I'm guessing because there is a cedet build built in to emacs something is crashing, I looked around the cedet and emacs sites, and did some googling to see if there was a way to upgrade it and I haven't seen the upgrade documentation probably due to the fact that emacs24 is pre-release and cedet1.1 is fairly new.

Cheers in advance... :)

Comment: is it still not working? Do you load CEDET in the start of your .emacs or later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please, take into account, that activation of CEDET 1.1 (and 1.0) differs from activation of CEDET bundled with Emacs. You need to use something like:

```
(load-file "..../cedet/common/cedet.el")
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
```

to load and activate it. This is old behavior is changed already in version that is currently in CEDET's repository - starting from this week, development switched to the same scheme as is used for CEDET in Emacs.

To read more about "old" activation scheme, please look to [my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) (although I want to update it with description of "new" activation scheme).

Comment: It is working sort of, semantic is a bit choppy, I can drop you an email with the full details if you want. And I would be really interested in seing an updated version of the article.. and cheers :)

Comment: Yes, please send me a e-mail (alexott at gmail) - I'll look, and maybe will post it to mailing list. Although, I think, that in the nearest time, people will busy with transitioning to "new" scheme.